# not strict inequalities in spring data queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm searching for a way to define queries in spring data repositories that are using non strict inequalities but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Let's say there's an entity class:

```
@Entity
class Person{
    @Id @Generated Integer id;
    int age;
}
```

and I'm creating a repository for that class. It's straightforward to create a query using a strict inequality:

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person,Integer>{
    List<Person> findByAgeGreaterThan(int a);
}
```

This will find all Persons with age > a
But I can't seem to find a way to implement a nonstrict inequality, i.e. age >= a

I've tried combining the queries with Or:
findByAgeOrAgeGreaterThan - this causes a runtime exception
Also I've tried to invert the query using the 'Not' keyword but that doesn't compile.

Is there really no other way but to use create your own custom query using the @Query annotation?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
List<Person> findByAgeGreaterThanEqual(int a);
```

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for a list of all supported method names.